# Deploy spatial plugin for neo4j on amazon aws?

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

I deployed an instance of neo4j on amazon aws accroding to this tutorial:

http://www.neo4j.org/develop/ec2

I would like to add the spatial plugin to this instance but I'm not sure what will be the best way of doing it.

My knowledge regarding linux / remote machines is limited for now (or Amazon aws...) so I'd appreciate some guidance.

Thank you!

Idea: I thought maybe I could edit the configuration file from the article so the spatial plugin will be installed when the stack is created?

Answer (score 1):

Installing the server plugin is fairly well documented at https://github.com/neo4j/spatial#using-the-neo4j-spatial-server-plugin.

- Connect to your ec2 instance using ssh -l ubuntu
- go to your neo4j directory (not sure which directory is used by default)
- download the matching version of server plugin using e.g. wget
- go to plugins directory
- unzip plugin `unzip ../neo4j-spatial-0.11-neo4j-1.9-server-plugin.zip`
- restart neo4j